# How to pass .env file variables to webpack config?

Tags: angularjs, webpack, environment-variables, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

I am new to webpack and worked out almost all build sections, but now the problem is that I want to pass the environment variables from a .env file to webpack config, so that I can pass that variables to my build files via `webpack.DefinePlugin` plugin.

Currently I am able to to pass environment variable directly from webpack to to my build. Please see the code below which I used in webpack.

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            "API_URL": JSON.stringify("http://my-api.com"),
            "FRONT_END_API_KEY" : "MYFRONTENDKEYGOESHERE"
        }),
```

My `package.json` build script is

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --progress --port 8000 --content-base app/build/src"
    }
```

Comment: really?! Is no one going to address the obvious issue here?  If you pass a secret into DefinePlugins, it is no longer a secret!!!

Only pass env variables that you are ok with being public.

Comment: @NSjonas No Secure Config values should be defined in the front-end ENV. The config values used in frontend can be intercepted by anyone. no matter where you save it in client-side. If you save it on client-side then it's open for anyone with basic programming skill can find it. moreover, no secure secrets should be saved at front-end .env, that has to be handled in server-side ENV. Nowadays all modern app solutions give out front-end and backend secrets separately with domain verification and all. eg: pusher,send-bird etc. 

Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @RameezRami

Yes...  My point is that none of these solutions point out that the author (and others below) is trying to pass secrets into an angular application!

Comment: I have updated the question. the whole purpose of the question was to get some value from a .env file. no one will be saving Secret API at frontend or in frontend .env . all of my secret keys are at backend .env.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

You can use [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) package for this purpose.

```
npm install dotenv --save
```

After installing the package, add this in the top of your config:

```
const webpack = require('webpack'); // only add this if you don't have yet

// replace accordingly './.env' with the path of your .env file 
require('dotenv').config({ path: './.env' });
```

then in `plugins` section, add this:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  "process.env": JSON.stringify(process.env),
}),
```

Comment: I tried this solution but for string variables it returns an object and not a string. for example, if i have DB_USERNAME=MY_USRNAME, and i try console.log(process.env.DB_USERNAME), it gives me MY_USRNAME object, a not "MY_USRNAME". i'm using dotenv 5.0.0. How can I solve it?

Comment: I had to turn the parsed dotenv into a valid json string with `JSON.stringify(dotenv.parsed)` for this to work.

Comment: You can also just make it more specific and do `"process.env.YOUR_VARIABLE": dotenv.parsed.YOUR_VARIABLE"` to avoid dealing with the whole object.  I only needed one variable in the webpack.config.js.

Comment: The line `"process.env": JSON.stringify(dotenv.parsed)` only passed variables defined in .env file, losing all the env vars set in the shell.

I had to require dotenv and then pass the actual process.env e.g.:
`"process.env": JSON.stringify(process.env)`

Comment: The line `"process.env": JSON.stringify(process.env);` shouldn't have a semicolon at the end, as it is an object key/value. It's a small thing though.

Comment: The big issue I had specifically with this answer was that my `bundle.js:formatted` had errors when I ran that line with a stringified object. I ended up having to be hacky and just hand it a string `const` like so: `"process.env": myEnvironmentString`, and although it was awkward (it passed a variable instead of a string to my React app), I was able to make it work. Your answer pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think the last snippet ("process.env": JSON.stringify(process.env),) is an horrible idea. You are exposing all secrets in your compilation. If this goes into a pipeline, ALL of your system environment variables are going to be exposed. On AWS, it means all of your secrets.

Comment: @DannyCoulombe shouldn't this line require('dotenv').config({ path: './.env' }); load only the env from that file?

Comment: @Computer'sGuy I think dotenv adds up on top of what's already in process.env. Again, not 100% sure, but I saw one of our junior push a similar thing in production once and we had all of our secrets exposed. All passwords, all secret keys, everything.

Comment: @Chololoco You have to clearly separate frontend ".env" and backend ".env".

Your secret keys shouldn't be on frontend ".env". in frontend env parsing occurs only at the build time. not at run time like a express server or similar. I hope this clears the confusion.

Comment: @Computer'sGuy i hope above comment also answers your confusion.

Comment: @RameezRami you don't understand. Your secrets aren't in .env. This file only adds up to the existing environment variables you already have in your OS. That's probably fine if you build locally, but if you have a job for instance that triggers a build on you CI whenever you push on a branch, that environment definitely has secrets and they will be exposed if you do JSON.stringify(process.env).

Comment: Agree with @Chololoco, this is really dangerous. It bundles all the env variables on the OS (not just the .env files), which may contain all sorts of secrets. It'll work, but I'd keep it well away from any non-local environment.

Comment: @garryp I thought that I could search by source code on Github and find projects that were implementing just that and found this one:
https://github.com/dsuryd/dotNetify/blob/4d98aac878d38a941525854f0238090f3af27b3f/DevApp/webpack.config.js#L55

And now, if you go on their main Github page, you'll find their website and on it, you'll see this file:
https://dotnetify.net/Scripts/Core/app.js

Now search for "process.env" in it and you'll see why this answer is an absolute catastrophy.

I have chosen a project that didn't had important secrets to not expose its flaws.

Answer (score 25):

## webpack + dotenv

I did get inspiration from the accepted answer, but it doesn't work for me. Maybe the API of dotenv has changed.

The following works for me

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
import { DefinePlugin } from 'webpack'


...

plugins: [
    new DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': JSON.stringify(dotenv.config().parsed)
    })
]

...
```

Comment: dotenv.config is not a function

Comment: @TSR It is. https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv/blob/7301ac9be0b2c766f865bbe24280bf82586d25aa/lib/main.js#L77

Comment: This bypasses the functionality of .env using actual environment variables when deployed.

Comment: @Liam webpack is mainly for bundling JS code to run in browser. And in browser you cannot access actual environment variables anyway. So I think the env vars is mainly for bundling time.

Comment: Maybe 10 years ago it was, but certainly not anymore. Node.js has been a thing for quite a while

Comment: @Liam For it not to override actual env vars, just rename 'process.env' to something else like "bundled.env". Then "bundled.env" for bundled env and "process.env" for actual env.

Answer (score 12):

It doesn't match your case exactly (although partially), but I've found this formula to be working best for me.

I use a combination of 2 libs: [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) to read the `.env` file for the `webpack.config.js` (configuration) needs, and [webpack-dotenv-plugin](https://github.com/nwinch/webpack-dotenv-plugin) **for the validation** (based on `.env.example` file) and **to pass** all the vars from .env file to the application code:

Part of my `webpack.config.js`:

```
// this is to load env vars for this config
require('dotenv').config({ // it puts the content to the "process.env" var. System vars are taking precedence
    path: '.env.webpack',
});
// and this to pass env vars to the JS application
const DotenvPlugin = require('webpack-dotenv-plugin');
```

plugins section:

```
plugins: [
    // ...
    new DotenvPlugin({ // makes vars available to the application js code
        path: '.env.webpack',
        sample: '.env.webpack.example',
        allowEmptyValues: true,
    }),
    // ...
]
```

Answer (score 9):

The simplest solution I found is to use this npm package: [dotenv-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack)

**Create a .env file**

```
// .env
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PASS=foobar
S3_API=mysecretkey
```

**Add it to your Webpack config file**

```
// webpack.config.js
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

module.exports = {
...
plugins: [
new Dotenv()
]
...
};
```

**Use in your code**

```
// file1.js
console.log(process.env.DB_HOST);
// '127.0.0.1'
Resulting bundle
// bundle.js
console.log('127.0.0.1');
```

Comment: I have this exact setting and unfortunately the `dotenv-webpack` plugin does not pass those variables to the `webpack.config.js` file, only the production code.

Comment: It is working with me man, it seems like you missed something.

Comment: It's not.  In case if you're trying to use these variables right inside your webpack.js file

Comment: This is a different problem. This plugin doesn't allow you to use dotenv in the webpack.config, which is what the question is asking about

Answer (score 5):

I can't comment to clarify any info so my apologies for the answer.

You could do:

```
var env = require('.env');
```

then

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            "API_URL": JSON.stringify("http://my-api.com"),
            "SECRET_KEY" : "MYSECRETKEYGOESHERE",
            "env_property": env.property
        }),
```

But I'm making assumptions about your .env file and the way its set up with this answer

Comment: Why are you stringifying the `API_URL`? And, why don't stringify also the `SECRET_KEY`?

Comment: Could you elaborate what assumptions you are making? this solution looks interesting in that you are exposing the value of the variable in your webpack.config file

Answer (score 5):

First off...

It appears that you are trying to pass secrets into an angular application.

**There is no such thing as a "secret" in client side (browser) javascript!!!**

Anything passed into `DefinePlugin` can be extracted with minimal effort.

Now that we've cleared that up....

Webpack now has the [Environment Plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/environment-plugin/) which makes it a bit easier to pass env variables into the GlobalDefine plugin.  From the docs:

```
new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin(['NODE_ENV', 'DEBUG']);
```

This is equivalent to the following DefinePlugin application:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
  'process.env.DEBUG': JSON.stringify(process.env.DEBUG)
});
```

If you are using `dotenv` to manage environment vars, you can use the [dotenv webpack plugin](https://github.com/mrsteele/dotenv-webpack).

It will only include variables that are referenced in your code, so as long as you don't reference your secrets, they won't be included.

Comment: Exactly. I have no doubt about that. anything given on front can be extracted. the whole question was for the idea of getting the variables from a .env file. ill be saving MAP_FRONT_END_KEY, ALGOLIA_SEARCH_KEY, similar front end API keys.

Comment: I see you have updated the question.  Before it really made it seem like you were trying to pass an actual secret.

Comment: Bro, it's just a sample text. instead of typing BLA_BLA, I typed YOUR_SECRETKEY_GOES _HERE. the whole point of the question is to get value from .env.

Comment: Bro Brah, variable names are significant, especially in "example" code with limited context.  If you put `"SECRET_KEY" : "MYSECRETKEYGOESHERE"`, of course I'm going to assume you believed this value would be kept secret.  There's a serious issue with people included secrets in their SPA, so I'm going to leave the first half of my answer as is.

Ty for updating the question so others won't assume it's ok to do this.

Answer (score 2):

From webpack [docs](https://webpack.js.org/guides/environment-variables/):

> The webpack command line environment option --env allows you to pass
>   in as many environment variables as you like. Environment variables
>   will be made accessible in your webpack.config.js. For example,
>   --env.production or --env.NODE_ENV=local (NODE_ENV is conventionally used to define the environment type, see here.)

in your `package.json`

```
webpack --env.NODE_ENV=local --env.production --progress
```

in your `webpack.config.js`

```
module.exports = env => {
  // Use env.<YOUR VARIABLE> here:
  console.log('NODE_ENV: ', env.NODE_ENV) // 'local'
  console.log('Production: ', env.production) // true

  return {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
      filename: 'bundle.js',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    }
```

Comment: The original question was about config variables stored in a `.env` file, not passed via the CLI so this wouldn't work AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I have many environments to support Ex: `.env.local`, `.env.dev`, ... etc. I have solved loading environment specific env file to webpack config as follows

**Step 1: Create a file for a specific environment - Ex: .env.local**

```
API_HOST=127.0.0.1
API_KEY=mysecretkey
...
```

**Step 2: Create a webpack config common for all environments - webpack.common.js**

```
...
...
const webpack = require('webpack')
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
...
...

module.exports = env => {
    return {
        resolve: {...},
        devServer: {...},
        module: {...},
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DefinePlugin(
               {'process.env': JSON.stringify(dotenv.config(path: env.ENV_FILE}).parsed)})
  }
}
```

Here the important thing to be noted is `module.exports` should [return a function](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-types/) instead of an object so that it can access the env variable (`ENV_FILE` in this example) passed on by the environment specific webpack config file, such as `webpack.local.js` (step 3).

**Step 3: Create a environment specific webpack config file - webpack.local.js**

```
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge')
const common = require('./webpack.common')

module.exports = env => merge(common(env), {
    mode: 'development',
    output: {
        publicPath: 'http://localhost:3000',
    },
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    devServer: {
        watchFiles: ['src/**/*'],
        hot: true,
        port: 3000
    },
})
```

In this environment specific file, webpack.common.js file is imported as a function (const `common`) that gets called with `env` parameter as part of the `webpack merge`. Here `env` parameter is populated by the `--env` option in the `webpack` command in the `package.json` (step 4)

**Step 4: Setup webpack commands in package.json**

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "webpack serve --open --env ENV_FILE=.env.local --config webpack.local.js",
  "build:prod": "webpack --env ENV_FILE=.env.prod --config webpack.prod.js"
  ...
}
```

Here npm command `start` serves up a local web server with `webpack.local.js` as its webpack config. When the call gets into `webpack.local.js` it populates `ENV_FILE` key into the `env` parameter in the function returned by `module.exports`.

Similarly you can setup `webpack.prod.js` which can be specific to your prod environment on the lines of webpack.local.js illustrated above.

Answer (score 0):

The **[dotenv-flow-webpack](https://github.com/kerimdzhanov/dotenv-flow-webpack)** can do this for you.

It is a webpack plugin that allows you to securely use environment variables within your javascript web application, loading them using *[dotenv-flow](https://github.com/kerimdzhanov/dotenv-flow)'s* `.env*` files loading strategy.

> *dotenv-flow* extends *[dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv)*, adding support of `NODE_ENV`-specific `.env*` files *like `.env.development`, `.env.test`, `.env.stage`, and `.env.production`,* and the appropriate `.env*.local` overrides allowing your app to have multiple environments with selectively-adjusted environment variable setups and load them dynamically depending on the current NODE_ENV.

Inspired by *[CreateReactApp](https://create-react-app.dev/)'s **storing configs in `.env*` files** approach*,
the *Twelve-Factor App methodology* in general, and *its **[store config in the environment](https://12factor.net/config)** section* in particular.

Comment: Your solution is the better one, as it allows each task to set which .env file to load. For instance, for dev and prod environments.