# unable to replace process.env.hostname in axios post method

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am new to UI/react and got work in my project to configure .env file. 
Since I have limited time, I tried to go through read.md of react where section for *Adding Custom Environment Variables* is mentioned.
It was mentioned there *The environment variables are embedded during the build time*. Hence I made changes as per [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46224986/how-to-pass-env-file-variables-to-webpack-config/46232148) so that build is not required and values could be read at runtime.

Inside action.js file of react project, I am trying to make post request as below. Console.log is printing the proper value but inside post request, URL is not getting replaced.

```
export function createIdea(idea) {
    return function (dispatch){
      return axios.post('http://${process.env.REACT_APP_HOSTNAME}:${process.env.REACT_APP_PORT}/users/user',JSON.stringify(user),config).then(response => {
      // dispatch
      console.log('success')
        dispatch({
          type: CREATE_SUCCESSFUL,
          payload:response.data
        })
      }).catch(response=>{
        // dispatch
        console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_HOSTNAME);
        console.log(response)
        dispatch({
          type: CREATE_FAILED,
          payload:response
        })
      })
    }
}
```

Inside webpack.config.dev.js, make changes to read configuration at runtime. Took reference from this [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46224986/how-to-pass-env-file-variables-to-webpack-config/46232148)
Changes are as below in webpack.config.dev.js:
At the top of the file , added

```
var dotenv = require('dotenv').config({path: '../.env'});
```

Inside plugins section, added

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            "process.env": dotenv.parsed
        }),
```

My .env file kept at root location looks as below:

```
REACT_APP_HOSTNAME=localhost

REACT_APP_PORT=8080
```

please provide some pointers if any configuration is missed or anything is misunderstood by me or something else need to be done wrt axios

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({         
  'process.env.REACT_APP_HOSTNAME':JSON.stringify(process.env.REACT_APP_HOSTNAME),
  'process.env.REACT_APP_PORT':JSON.stringify(process.env.REACT_APP_PORT)
})
```

Comment: I tried this approach but still same error. Unable to resolve the URL

Answer (score 0):

Create an axios configuration file so you don't have to repeat the URL over and over:

```
import axios from "axios";

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL // or process.env.BASE_URL if not using CRA
});

export default api;
```

Now you'll import this configuration for AJAX requests:

`import api from '../path/to/utils/axiosConfig.js';`

If you use the [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app), then `react-scripts` allows you to use `.env` files automagically. See [create-react-app documentation](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables).

**Working CRA example**:

[image: Edit ENVs]

---

However, if you're like me, and using a custom webpack configuration, then here's a working example: [custom-webpack-envs](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/custom-webpack-envs)

The `dotenv` implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/custom-webpack-envs/blob/master/webpack.config.js#L1) and [here](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/custom-webpack-envs/blob/master/config/plugins.js#L55-L60):

To run the example above...

1. Open a terminal on your desktop.
2. Clone the repo: `git clone git@github.com:mattcarlotta/custom-webpack-envs.git`
3. Change the directory: `cd custom-webpack-envs`
4. Install the dependencies: `yarn install`
5. Run the server: `yarn dev`