# why my env file with a personal access token is not working in my react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, environment-variables, graphql

My react app gets user data from github using graphql and the requests are made through a personal access token on a `.env` file.

My `.env` file is on the `root` folder of my project. The key is on the left and the key value (personal access token) is on the right:

`.env` file: `REACT_APP_GITHUB_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN=xxxXXX`

My code is in the `App.js` file which is inside the `component` folder which is inside the `src` folder.
Path to `App.js` -> `./src/components/App.js`

Inside my `App.js` I have the following code on lines 6-10:

```
const axiosGitHubGraphQL = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://api.github.com/graphql',
  headers: {
    Authorization: `bearer ${process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
  },
});
```

Through this code I can make requests to github using my personal access token which is inside the `.env` file, but the file is not working.

Dos anyone have a clue why my `.env` file does not work?

My react app is on github on the link:https://github.com/rvmelo/tech6-app

(NOTE: I followed the first steps from the tutorial on this link: https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-with-graphql-tutorial/)

Comment: I'm not sure if was a typo of yours but I believe it is `.env` and not `env.`

Comment: sorry I made a mistake it is already `.env` in my project I just wrote in the wrong way in my question...

Comment: this feature is available with `react-scripts@0.2.3 and higher`, you need to use this

Comment: which feature??

Comment: using `.env` in react app

Comment: Actually this feature is available from "react-scripts@0.5.0 and higher." https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env

Comment: my react script is version 3.0.0 so a don't think this is the problem...

Comment: your `package.json` doesn't point that you are using `react-scripts`, instead the script `dev` execs `webpack-dev-server`

Comment: how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This feature of autoloading the `.env` is a `react-scripts` stuff.

As you are using `webpack-dev-server` to develop, you should load this manually.

You can use `dotenv` package for this purpose.

```js
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config({path: __dirname + '/.env'});
```

In webpack config plugins section use

```js
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  "process.env": dotenv.parsed
}),
```

See more: [How to pass .env file variables to webpack config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46224986/how-to-pass-env-file-variables-to-webpack-config)

Comment: sorry I made a mistake it is already  `.env` in my project I just wrote in the wrong way in my question...

Comment: I analyze your source code and change my answer accordingly ;)

Comment: still not working... that is how I did: I put `var dotenv = require('dotenv').config({path: '/home/user/react-projects/react-app' + '/.env'});`  at the top of the config file and `new webpack.DefinePlugin({"process.env": dotenv.parsed}), ` in the plugin section of the config file

Answer (score 1):

I am currently following the same tutorial  https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-with-graphql-tutorial/, I ran to the same issue.

The solution would be to have a personal access token first created on GitHub, then copy it to your .env file which should live in the root directory.
then save the file and  restart the application.

cancel and terminate the react app an npm start it again.this enables env variables to be picked up automatically.I noticed env variables have to be restarted to function

```
const axxiosGitHubGraphQL= axios.create({
  baseURL:"https://api.github.com/graphql",
  headers:{
    Authorization: `bearer ${
      process.env.REACT_APP_GITHUB_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
    }
  }
);
```