# error using dotenv-webpack with react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, dotenv

Hi I am trying to use `dotenv-webpack` with my webpack config file and I can't seem to figure what to do with the following error...

```
.definitions is not a valid Plugin property
- Maybe you meant to use
"plugin": [
  ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime", {
  "definitions": {
    "process.env.REACT_APP_WEATHERAPI": "\"XXXXXXX\""
  }
}]
]
```

I am following the docs for using dotenv-webpack.

```
Here is my webpack.config fileconst currentTask = process.env.npm_lifecycle_event;
const path = require("path");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const { postcss } = require("postcss-mixins");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const fse = require("fs-extra");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const dotenv = require("dotenv-webpack");

const postCSSPlugins = [
  require("postcss-import"),
  require("postcss-mixins"),
  require("postcss-simple-vars"),
  require("postcss-nested"),
  require("postcss-hexrgba"),
  require("autoprefixer")
];

class RunAfterCompile {
  apply(compiler) {
    compiler.hooks.done.tap("Copy images", function () {
      fse.copySync("./app/assets/images", "./docs/assets/images");
    });
  }
}

let cssConfig = {
  test: /\.css$/i,
  use: [
    "css-loader?url=false",
    { loader: "postcss-loader", options: { plugins: postCSSPlugins } }
  ]
};

let pages = fse
  .readdirSync("./app")
  .filter(function (file) {
    return file.endsWith(".html");
  })
  .map(function (page) {
    return new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: page,
      template: `./app/${page}`
    });
  });

let config = {
  entry: "./app/assets/scripts/App.js",
  plugins: pages,
  module: {
    rules: [
      cssConfig,
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-react", "@babel/preset-env"],
            plugins: ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime", new dotenv()] <---- ERROR HERE!
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};

if (currentTask == "dev") {
  cssConfig.use.unshift("style-loader");
  config.output = {
    filename: "bundled.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "app")
  };
  config.devServer = {
    before: function (app, server) {
      server._watch("./app/**/*.html");
    },
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "app"),
    hot: true,
    port: 3000,
    host: "0.0.0.0",
    historyApiFallback: { index: "/" }
  };
  config.mode = "development";
}

if (currentTask == "build") {
  cssConfig.use.unshift(MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader);
  postCSSPlugins.push(require("cssnano"));
  config.output = {
    filename: "[name].[chunkhash].js",
    chunkFilename: "[name].[chunkhash].js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "docs")
  };
  config.mode = "production";
  config.optimization = {
    splitChunks: { chunks: "all" }
  };
  config.plugins.push(
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: "styles.[chunkhash].css" }),
    new RunAfterCompile()
  );
}

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [using dotenv with react & webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64492196/using-dotenv-with-react-webpack)

Comment: no it did not answer my question because I am still having that same error :/

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Your `new dotenv()` is placed inside the wrong plugins array. [Docs.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack)

It should be in the global plugins not in `babel-loader`. Since you already have generated an array of `HtmlWebpackPlugin`, you would have to add it to the existing array

Your plugins array should be:

```js
let config = {
  ...
  plugins: [
    ...pages,
    new dotenv()
  ]
  ...
};
```

Comment: thank you for the response. unfortunately, I am still getting the same exact error after your suggestion.

Comment: Sorry, just realized that you have `new dotenv()` inside the `babel-loader` plugins when it should be placed in the global plugins array. I have edited my answer.

Comment: After changing my config to be `plugins: [pages, new dotenv()]` i recieved a `Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.` Thanks for trying to help out.

Comment: Just to make sure, did you add `new dotenv()` to the `pages` array? `pages` is an array and you need to add the `dotenv`object to the array. My solution has `plugins: [...pages, new dotenv()]`

Comment: It works!!! i ended up adding `config.plugins.push('new dotenv())` to my `if(currentTask == "dev"){...}` and that did the trick