# Unable to access process.env variables with dotenv-webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, dotenv

I'm trying to access my .env file variables using dotenv-webpack so that they can be bundled later and I can use them on my website, however I followed the instructions and have looked online and can't make it work.

```
//.env
VAR=1234
```

```
// created a webpack.config.js with the following code
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new Dotenv()
  ]
};
```

```
// index.js
console.log(process.env.VAR);
// undefined
```

I'm not sure what to do because I've followed the example in: https://github.com/mrsteele/dotenv-webpack and it seems like it should be easy...

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by Pandhu Wibowo, please give him the thumbs up, I managed to make it work using webpack-cli, webpack and dotenv packages.
[How to pass .env file variables to webpack config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46224986/how-to-pass-env-file-variables-to-webpack-config)

```
./env 
VAR=1234
```

```
./webpack.config.js
const webpack = require('webpack'); 

// replace accordingly './.env' with the path of your .env file 
require('dotenv').config({ path: './.env' }); 

const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env": JSON.stringify(process.env)
    }),
  ]
};
```

```
./package.json
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack"
  },
```

```
npm run start
--> creates the bundle.js which will include the env variable
```

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to use `dotenv-webpack` package to define environments files, you need to tell it where is your **.env** file, here's what I did:

`webpack.dev.js`

- Import it:

```
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');
```

- Use it in plugins array and pass to it `.env.developement` path:

```
plugins: [
      ...,
      new Dotenv({
        path: `${environmentsPath}/.env.development`,
        systemvars: true, //Set to true if you would rather load all system variables as well (useful for CI purposes)
      }),
    ],
```

`webpack.prod.js`

- Import it:

```
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');
```

- Use it in plugins array and pass to it `.env` path:

```
plugins: [
      ...,
      new Dotenv({
        path: `${environmentsPath}/.env`,
        systemvars: true, //Set to true if you would rather load all system variables as well (useful for CI purposes)
      }),
    ],
```

The good thing I like about this approach is that you can override the environment file using `env-cmd` package (e.g: `"build:staging": "env-cmd -f environments/.env.staging webpack --config buildTools/webpack.prod.js --progress --color"`)

Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: Adding `systemvars: true` worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This was the complementary point for me:

> To access environment variables from the client app they must be
> prefixed with REACT_APP_. Otherwise they will only be accessible on
> the server side.

so my .env file looks like

```
REACT_APP_API_KEY=my-api-key
REACT_APP_SECRET=secretInfo2
```

With the help of: https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2022/06/22/react-access-environment-variables-from-dotenv-env

Answer (score 0):

I was just trying to access my `.env` variables during development, not even building my app yet, and couldn't access any through the other methods using `dot-env-webpack` or `DefinePlugin`. This way worked out for me:

```js
new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin({
  NODE_ENV: 'development', // use 'development' unless process.env.NODE_ENV is defined
  DEBUG: false,
});
```

Read more: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/environment-plugin/

Answer (score -1):

Why you don't use `dotenv` package?

[dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)

Comment: Because dotenv package doesn't let me bundle the .env variables and access them on my website. I was trying to pass an API key from my .env folder and then let the website use this API key when its running. Yet I don't. want to expose the API key when adding the project to github

Comment: Can you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46224986/how-to-pass-env-file-variables-to-webpack-config

Comment: It worked! I will add exactly what I did below!! Thank you, that was a very helpful stackoverflow link, took some time to make it work but I managed to wrap my head around it :)

Comment: Awesome! Good job!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @PandhuWibowo Comments should not be posted as an answer