# How to access environment variable in react?

Tags: reactjs, django

I added react into django using webpack and when I created `.env` file in `app_name/`, I am trying to access environment variable like this `process.env.base_url` but I am getting undefined.

file structure

```
Django_React

  -- app_name
       -- src
       -- .env
       -- urls.py
       ...
       ...
  ...
  ...
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./static/js"),
    filename: "[name].js",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js|.jsx$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: "babel-loader",
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env": {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("development"),
      },
    }),
  ],
};
```

How can I create and access environment variable if react app is created like this ?

Comment: You'll need to properly inject the env variables into your compiled JS code through webpack. Can you show your webpack config?

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46224986/how-to-pass-env-file-variables-to-webpack-config). Basically, use the dotenv plugin to load env variables from file into your webpack environment

Answer (score 0):

Such issue could lead from naming convention.

According to [React Doc - Adding Custom Environment Variables](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/)

> You must create custom environment variables beginning with `REACT_APP_`. Any other variables except `NODE_ENV` will be **ignored** to avoid accidentally [exposing a private key on the machine that could have the same name](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/865#issuecomment-252199527).

So, maybe you could try to

1. add `REACT_APP_` at the beginning of your environment variable name, like `process.env.REACT_APP_base_url`;
2. restart the development server;
3. access environment variable by `process.env.REACT_APP_base_url`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This solution did not work for me, I was able to solve from accepted solution given here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46224986/how-to-pass-env-file-variables-to-webpack-config)