# Fullstack accessing simple string from node, webpack and react

Tags: reactjs, node.js, webpack, config, dotenv

I thought this would be a simple taks, but it's proving impossible.

I got this project structure

```
project-root/
├── .env
├── config/
├── node/
├── server.js
└── app/
    ├── src/
    │   └── home.tsx
    └── webpack/
        └── options.js
```

Basically all I want is to have a simple string to be accessible by `server.js`, `home.tsx` and `options.js` this last one is a file that's part of the webpack setup.

I have tried `dotenv` and `config` but `webpack` is not having it.

Any ideas?

Note:

I need this string to load as part of the proxy config in the dev webpack configuration so loading it as a plugin will fail as I need this string ready before that.

The `server.js` accessing the variable

```
import 'dotenv/config'
...
app.use(`/${process.env.APP_API}`, router)

router.get('/main', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello')
})
```

The `webpack` dev config

```
...
devServer: {
  publicPath: '/',
  open: true,
  https: false,
  port: localPort,
  proxy: {
    [`/${process.env.APP_API}`]: {
      target: `http://localhost:${apiPort}`,
      secure: false
    }
 },
...
```

The react `Home.tsx` file accessing the string

```
const connectBackEnd = async () => {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios(`/${process.env.APP_API}/main`)
    setText(data)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass .env file variables to webpack config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46224986/how-to-pass-env-file-variables-to-webpack-config)

Comment: Not at all, I need to access this string before the webpack loads the plugins. The string itself is a configuration parameter for the proxy api in the webpack dev config

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I did this from `options.js` on webpack

```
import { resolve } from 'path'
import { config } from 'dotenv'

const envPath = resolve(__dirname, '../../.env')

config({ path: envPath })

console.log(process.env.APP_API)
```

Comment: Another option that doesn't involve changing your code is something like [env-cmd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/env-cmd) which you incorporate into your `package.json` scripts. Means your code is less tied to directory structure

Comment: As @Phil mentioned, you should avoid reading environment variables from within your code. Instead, environment variable injection should always be external to your code so that when your Node code runs, all the variables are available directly on `process.env` object. Use [dotenv-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-cli), [env-cmd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/env-cmd) or something similar.

Comment: This environment variable name is just the string for the proxy api name that the app uses for front end and webpack to know where to go with axios and the server to know where to expect the route. Are you suggesting writting it on the package JSON how else given the structure of the project do I access this string?