# Run ng build with custom configurations

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular7

I have Angular project which I would like to deploy on Apache server. I use `ng build` but I would like to custom address and endpoint for backend.

proxy.conf.json:

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

This configuration is not applied at all. 
How I can set it properly in order to change configurations?

Environment ts file:

```
import {environment as prod} from './environment.prod';

export const environment = Object.assign(prod, {
  production: false
});
```

Comment: Why not to use enviroment files?

Comment: I added my environment file. How I need to configure it?

Comment: which version of angular you are using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Properly using environment.ts in my angular4 application with angular-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43258421/properly-using-environment-ts-in-my-angular4-application-with-angular-cli)

Answer (score 11):

You can define different environment files. Below example for "dev":

```
export const environment = {
    production: false,
    envName: 'dev',
    configPath: './assets/config/config.dev.json'
    ...
};
```

Add a configuration part for "dev" in "angular.json" file, like that:

```
"dev": {
  "fileReplacements": [
    {
      "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
      "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
    }
  ],
  ....
```

And use this command to build : `ng build --configuration=dev`

For more information, take a look at this post : [How to set environment via `ng serve` in Angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50174584/how-to-set-environment-via-ng-serve-in-angular-6)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using Angular (>v6), and you have created multiple environment files as per requirements.

So what you need to do is, go to angular.json file

```
angular.json > projects > projectName > architect > build > configurations > fileReplacements
```

and here you need to replace files name with your files name like this -

```
"replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
"with": "src/environments/environment.live.ts"
```